# how to set limit of visible elements with show more button in <amp-list>?

Tags: amp-html, amp-email, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

how should i use <amp-list> to parse json file but show limit number of elements of it on page, so that i can set up a show more button to load more elements? i use it to make a block with article recomendations for an amp email.

maybe there any other ways i can implement this block with amp usable in emails?

i'm trying to use [example of dynamic updating from amp.dev](https://playground.amp.dev/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpreview.amp.dev%2Fdocumentation%2Fexamples%2Finteractivity-dynamic-content%2Fdynamically_updating_items_in_a_feed&_gl=1*yahsi1*_ga*YW1wLXNXRXhoWjJ4eVA1NUtDT0Q5bkJ5SkE.) but when [i change](https://playground.amp.dev/?_gl=1*vr6g31*_ga*YW1wLXNXRXhoWjJ4eVA1NUtDT0Q5bkJ5SkE.&mode=Responsive#share=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) link to another json file, it shows every element set in file and next button don't work properly like in an example

Answer (score 0):

The example you linked uses an endpoint that returns a random image every time it's fetched. It's not really paging through a list of fixed images.

The AMP for Website format supports what you described using the `load-more` attribute of `amp-list`, but it's not supported in AMP for Email. To achieve the behavior in AMP for Email, you can do something like this:

1. Use `amp-list` to display the initial page
2. Use `amp-form` to display subsequent pages upon clicking on a button. The form can render an `amp-mustache` template upon a successful submission. The JSON used to render the template should have a dynamic size based an an integral form input.
3. Use `amp-bind` to manipulate the integral form input, e.g., make it increase by 10 every time the form is submitted. You can attach a `tap` event listener on the button to execute the `setState` action to change `amp-state` and then submit the above-mentioned form.